# windows phone 7: how to create an application theme?

Tags: themes, windows-phone-7, styles

I would like to define a theme for my Windows Phone 7 application, to be applied at application launch regardless of the system theme set by the "Settings" phone menu. How can this be done?

I see on MSDN that Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" allows the control using that brush to respond to system-wide theme changes. How can I do the same thing: to allow the control to get its brush, not from the system settings, but from my application settings?

And where should I put those settings, in order to have one style settings file that I can access from anywhere in my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no theme specific API in Silverlight. What you have is one or several resources dictionnary/ies that you can use to define a set of styles to be applied to your controls.

in Theme1.xaml file :

```
<Style x:Key="HeadingStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

in Theme2.xaml file :

```
<Style x:Key="HeadingStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

in App.xaml (the default theme or reference a default.xaml file):

```
<Application.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="HeadingStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="blue"/>
  </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

To change the current "theme" :

```
Application.Current.Resources = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("Theme2.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

I don't have right now the RTM tools installed so I can't test this code.

Comment: You pretty much nailed it. According to the documentation, you can only override the system theme if you explicitly modify the control properties that are affected by a theme. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402557%28VS.92%29.aspx